# Android (4 and higher) keyboard makes visible button not clickable

Tags: android, keyboard

When I click on Edittext, keyboard appears. There is a button that is still visible when the keyboard is on, but it's not clickable. You can click that button only when you hit "back" button and keyboard dissapears. I want to be able to click that button even when the keyboard is visible. This problem is only with 4 and higher android versions, everything is fine in older versions.

How can I make that visible button would be clickable even when the keyboard is popped out?

Here's the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:mm="http://millennialmedia.com/android/schema"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/topLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/top_logo" />      

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchField"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLogo"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
</EditText>   

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchField"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/search_button_label"  />        

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns own `<com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView/>` was causing problems. It was in the same RelativeLayout with all other components. Putting MMAdView to another layout inside the main layout solved the problem.